# How to debug .app bundle crash-on-startup on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, debugging, app-bundle

What is the best way to find out why an .app bundle immediately crashes when started? Does Mac OS X store logs anywhere?

For example, this does not work, and crashes immediately:

```
open /Applications/MyApp.app
```

However, calling the executable directly seems to work:

```
/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppLauncher
```

`Info.plist` should be fine and point to the right executable:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>MyAppLauncher</string>
```

For all I know, OS X never even calls my code. How can I find out what it is doing, and why it is failing?

**Note:** This application uses sandboxing, so I presume it has something to do with that. But I'd like to see some logs that confirm that.

Comment: Start `Console.app`.

Comment: How would that help? `open /Applications/MyApp.app` doesn't give you console output, even if you run it from the console.

Comment: If your app is crashing it should be producing a crash log.  You can view that log in `Console.app`.

Comment: Where would I find this `crash log`? Assuming it doesn't show?

Comment: In `Console.app` somewhere.  It should be obvious once you open that app.

Comment: I see. OK, I'll have a look if something pops up in the syslog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Run the console app, you can find it with spotlight
2. Run your app
3. at the bottom of the list, you will see messages the app is sending to log, for eaxmple:
   `MyApp(14489) deny mach-lookup com.apple.networkd`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, The Console app idea was great. But in my case, I was trying to open the package in a location different from /Applications. Copying it to /Applications solved my issue.

I got this message in the Console, which wasn’t very clear what the problem really was:
`fault  23:35:12.833776-0300    runningboardd   RunningBoard launch requested for identifier  launched process with different identifier QtMeshEditor`

Hope this helps anyone running in a similar issue.